# Unsure how to release memory caused by function in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My problem is being unable or not knowing how to clear the memory being flooded by images (bitmaps) not being used anymore. The function's purpose is to change the background of the form to a new image every x amount of seconds.

The memory usage will inevitably overflow and it will crash. But even when I am changing to a different window, I run this.Close() and the memory usage is still constantly increasing.

Here is the function:

```
public async void WaitSomeTime(String[] favs, int time)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        favs = favs.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
        foreach (string fav in favs)
        {
            await Task.Delay(time);
            Image img = new Bitmap(fav);
            this.pictureBoxBG.Image = img;
        }
                

    }
}
```

So far I've tried the Dispose method but to no avail, I don't completely understand it. I've tried the 'using' statement but that causes an error in Program.cs (entry point). I'm sure it's a simple fix but I'm out of ideas and GPT3 isn't helping very well, thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be better accomplished with a simple Timer object, and on each Tick event display a random image. Your existing endless loop will cause you many headaches.

Comment: Whatever method you choose to loop the images, add `pictureBoxBG.Image?.Dispose(); pictureBoxBG.Image = new Bitmap(fav);` -- To use that kind of loop, pass a CancellationToken to the method and, in the method, to `Task.Delay()`; also check `[CancellationToken].IsCancellationRequested` to terminate the loop when not needed anymore

Comment: Could you just bind Image path to UI, this way Framework takes care of disposing it when image changes?

Comment: @Gary but _which_ timer object when the choices include `System.Threading.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer`, `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, `System.Web.UI.Timer`and `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`. Some have potential reentrancy issues and others don't. Some marshal the tick onto the UI thread and others don't. Some are more portable than others. One of the more modern takes is the `PeriodicTimer` introduced in .NET 6 (see this MVP [blog](https://www.ilkayilknur.com/a-new-modern-timer-api-in-dotnet-6-periodictimer)) but it's rather similar in nature to the approach taken here.

Comment: That will certainly happen with this code.  It needs if (this.pictureBoxBG.Image != null) this.pictureBoxBG.Image.Dispose(); before the Image property assignment.  So you release the unmanaged memory used up by the previous bitmap.

Comment: @IVSoftware. This is a first time poster, so I'm assuming some basic timer requirements like a simple Windows.Forms.Timer, unless further detail is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **Diagnostic Tools** in Visual Studio we can get an idea of how your current code behaves with respect to process memory over a ~5-minute period. Updates are set to occur ~10 times a second to provide a test load. Even though the image files I'm using for testing aren't very big the effect on memory consumption is apparent.

[image: before]

---

One approach you could try that seems to keep this it in check is to explicitly dispose of images and then collect garbage. It seems reasonable to apply this after each complete pass through the list of favs but you get general drift and can apply it wherever you choose.

*To be clear, the critical step is to Dispose the previous image and GC will take care of it from there. But if your goal is to keep the footprint as low as possible this "extraordinary measure" allows you to exercise more control.*

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBoxBG.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        string dir = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images");
        string[] favs = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(_=>Path.Combine(dir, $"image-{_}.png")).ToArray();
        _task = WaitSomeTime(favs, 100);
    }
    Task _task;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public async Task WaitSomeTime(String[] favs, int time)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            List<Image> trash= new List<Image>();
            favs = favs.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
            foreach (string fav in favs)
            {
                await Task.Delay(time);
                if(pictureBoxBG.Image != null)
                {
                    trash.Add(pictureBoxBG.Image);
                }
                Image img = new Bitmap(fav);
                pictureBoxBG.Image = img;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < trash.Count; i++)
            {
                trash[i].Dispose();
                trash[i] = null;
            }
            // Requesting an expedited disposal of managed memory.
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: after]

Comment: Aside from that, the way you are handling the periodic updates asynchronously is similar to the [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer.waitfornexttickasync?view=net-7.0#remarks) class that was introduced in .NET 6 (probably good in other words as `PeriodicTimer` is considered a "modern" approach that addresses the potential problem of reentrancy).